# How can I play a single PCM sample in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, wav, pcm, audio-player

I intend to pass PCM samples into my audio card in bulk only when I want at speed I choose. The best solution for me in this case would be to have a function that takes one PCM sample, passes it into the audio card and plays it.

Is there a library to do this? I've tried alsaaudio which lets me write PCM data to its `alsaaudio.device`, but only starts to play once I finish writing data to it (how they accomplished that is a great wonder for me).

If not, can I write a simple function to do that?

Answer (score -1):

According to Wikipedia, a single sample is just a numeric value representing current "amplitude" of the playback device. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing))

Standard sampling frequency of audio files starts at 44.1 kHz. This means You have at least 44100 samples per second. So do You really want to play the audio samples one by one? I am not sure, but probably it is not possible them one by one since operation of transfering data to audiodevice coasts much.

I propose You to play packets of samples. Consider sending several thousands of samples. Experiment what value makes sounding smooth and minimizes initial delay.